# Function return value changes if use local variable

Tags: r

I have two snippets of code which I would have expected to behave the same, but they don't:

```
  position <- function(t) {
    coordinates <- c(cosh(t), sinh(t))

    return(coordinates[1])
  }
```

and

```
  position <- function(t) {
    coordinates <- c(cosh(t), sinh(t))

    return(cosh(t))
  }
```

I use the function `position` to plot a curve. With the first snippet the curve is not plotted. With the second snippet the curve is plotted.

What is the functional difference between the two snippets, and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of

```
coordinates <- c(cosh(t), sinh(t))
```

is a numeric vector of length `2 * length(t)`.

The command

```
return(coordinates[1])
```

returns only the first value of this vector. (The result of `coordinates[1]` and `cosh(t)` are only identical if `length(t) == 1`.) To return the result of `cosh(h)`, you could index `coordinates` with a sequence based on the length of `t`:

```
coordinates <- c(cosh(t), sinh(t))

return(coordinates[seq_along(t)])
```

Comment: Thanks. That's a step forward. But now I cannot add a vector to the list, and do matrix multiplication on it.

Comment: @Randomblue I modified my answer accordingly.

Comment: I'm confused. What does `seq_along` do? What is `x` in your example? I want modify `position` (e.g. `position + c(1, 1)`), and then extract the first coordinate.

Comment: @Randomblue Sorry, I replaced `x` with `t`. The function `seq_along(t)` creates a sequence from 1 to `length(t)`. For example: `seq_along(c(3,5,2,6,1)) == c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)`.

Comment: The `seq_along` operation is unnecessary. You would get the same with just `return(coordinates)`, but if the goal is to return a matrix, it is the `c()` step that is causing the problems.

Comment: @DWin It seems like the user wants to return the result of `cosh(t)` which is a part of `coordinates`. In the first version of my answer I recommended using a list, but this wasn't appreciated.

Comment: `coordinates[seq_along(t)]` will just be `cosh(t)` since you are effectively dropping the `sinh(t)` calculations.

Answer (score 3):

What gets returned will depend on the type of argument passed. If the argument "t" is a matrix as might be expected for a function designed to deal with coordinates, than a matrix is returned from `cosh(t)` and from `sinh(t)`.

The first function would only return the first element of a matrix formed and then "straightened out" as the `c` function caused it to loose dimensions. If you wanted to preserve the matrix character, then use `rbind` or `cbind` depending on what would be the next function to process the data.

The second function would first calculate "coordinates" and then let it disappear into the garbage collector since it returns the matrix formed by `cosh(t)` instead.

You will not be able to get a better answer since you are at the moment making us all guess about what sort of data structure you are passing to the function. You should post the results of `dput()` on your argument to this function. And you should tell us what the help page for the plotting function expects as an argument type.

Answer (score 0):

Use double brackets in your first example.

```
  coordinates[[1]]
```

---

As a useful tip when troubleshooting, if you explore the output of your two functions using `str(position(x))` for your two different functions, you should see the difference.

Try also

```
   str(vec[1])
   str(vec[[1]])
```

Comment: If you look at the outputs of cosh(t) and coordinates[1] you will see that they are clearly different.  As @sven pointed out, you want to use a list, and you want to reference with double brackets.

Comment: "coordinates" cannot be a list since `cosh` and `sinh` would have returned either a matrix or a a vector (or an error if t were a list). So c(cosh(t),sinh(t)) would be a vector and using "[[" would cause an error.